# What is the best way to create class with nested class?

Tags: typescript

I have class. They look like:

```
export class TestObject {

  constructor(init?: Partial<TestObject>) {
    Object.assign(this, init);
  }

  id: number;
  name: string;
  well: Well;

}

export class Well {

  constructor(init?: Partial<Well>) {
    Object.assign(this, init);
  }

  id: number;
  name: string;
  x: number;
  y: number;
}
```

I received object from backend.

```
obj = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'first',
  well: {
    id: 2,
    name: 'second',
    x: 1,
    y: 1
  }
}
```

What is the best way to create a instance of TestObject class, so that well property was Well class member?

It's ok or not?

// modify constructor

```
constructor(init?: Partial<TestObject>) {
    Object.assign(this, init);
    this.well = new Well(init.well);
  }
```

// create instance

```
const myObj = new TestObject(obj);
```

I need it for typescript decorators.

Comment: It's ok if it works for your use case. So, you might add your use case if you want more specific advice. (what's in your JSON? Do you really need to create class instances or would an array of user data suffice? Just something that I'm wondering...)

Comment: @Kokodoko
I really need to create class instance, because i would like to use decorators.
E.g.
In my TestObject class
`@exportable()
well: Well`. In my Well class: `@exportable() name: string`. If myObj.well isn't member of Well class, then my decorators doesn't work. It's predictable and understandable. I don't know another way, if I don't create property `well` as Well class member.